# Use parallel hint in coldfusion query

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, cfquery

How do you use the parallel hint in a ColdFusion query? I tried this query

`select /*+ parallel */ x.*...`

However, it is not working. I think it is taking the hint it as comment.

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Step 1 - specify your RDBMS.  Step 2 - clarify "not working" in terms of what you are trying to achieve vs what is actually happening.

Comment: FYI, without more details I am guessing you are using Oracle. If that is incorrect, please update the question tags.  Also, in addition to providing a description of the actual versus expected results, please include your CF version (9, 10, 11, etcetera) and the *full* query code.

Comment: The hint syntax looks correct but there are many reasons why parallelism won't work.  First, you should narrow down whether it's purely a database problem or an application problem.  Run the query on an Oracle IDE, and check a query like `select * from gv$px_process;` to see if it's really running in parallel.  Also look at an explain plan, for example: `explain plan for select /*+ parallel */ ... ;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.

Comment: It is an application problem ,the query is working fine in oracle,as I told u when I am using this parallel in coldfusion as a coldfusion query it take this /* as a comment so the parallel is not working  and it takes almost 5 m inutes to retrieve 10000+ records.

Comment: @RaviKumar - Please do not *describe* the code, just post it :-) Some things we can only tell from seeing the *actual code*. For example, you tagged the question with cfquery. In CFML, comments are indicated by `<!--- ---->`, NOT `/* ... */`, so what you described should not happen. However, since we cannot see the actual query code you are using, that is just a guess.

Comment: @Leigh `/* ... */` is a comment in a CFScript tag. If it is in CFScript then an easy thing to try would be to put it in a CFML query tag instead - but as you said, without any code it is just a guess.

Comment: @MT0 - Yes, I am aware of that ;-) However, the point I was trying to make is that there was obviously some ambiguity (dbms, using cfml versus cfscript, etcetera) and that is why they have not received an answer yet.  In order to answer the question, we need to see the *full* code, not just parts of it.